Desperate father occupies hospital
The movie is about an African-American family, whose son has a disease. The family has economical issues, and can't afford a hospital bill. The family end up selling their property, but still doesn't have enough money.
As the parents become more and more desperate, the mother end up screaming "Do something!" to her husband.
The father then occupies a hospital and takes hostages. He refuses to leave until his son has been cured.
Meanwhile special forces has been sent into the buildings ventilation pipes to take out the father, but in some way the father doesn't get hit.
The movie ends with a traffic accident, and the victim dies and has the required organ to save the son. The dead body is rushed to the hospital and the son gets cured.

I think David has the right answer with "John Q".

I think that you are looking for John Q


John Quincy Archibald takes a hospital emergency room hostage when his insurance won't cover his son's heart transplant.

